# subversion ignore nestered externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I'm working on a big project using subversion, and we use externals everywhere. This makes an "svn up" take forever since it has a delay on each external. To fix this, I want to remove some nested externals. Is there a way to add an external but specify that you don't want IT'S externals?

```
Example layout, where "A -> B" means "dir A is an external of B":
/modules/testfiles
/modules/mymodule
/modules/mymodule/testfiles -> /modules/testfiles
/proj/mymodule -> /modules/mymodule

That last external adds the nested "testfiles" external:
/proj/mymodule/testfiles -> /modules/mymodule/testfiles -> /modules/testfiles
```

Is there a way to prevent nested externals like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware that this is possible with `svn`. You could look into `svn up --ignore-externals` and see whether this helps. Alternatively, you can try to `svn up --set-depth empty <dir>` on those (external) directories you do not wish to update.

Comment: The problem with this for me is that I do an "svn up" from the base directory.. and there's probably about 15 externals, and half of those have nested externals... so short of writing a script to cherrypick which externals to up, I'm hosed

Comment: You only need to do `svn up --set-depth` once for a working directory. Subversion remembers this. So, next time you can just do `svn up` at the top level.

Comment: Marking as correct because it's the best current solution I can find.. real pity subversion doesn't support this at the repo level